# SQL Update a table, use Case expression, then sum a column to get the total

Tags: sql-server

i'm updating a table with a case expression and then having trouble finding a way to sum a column to get the total, would appreciate any input.
thanks in advance.
Dave

--Declare & Set Variables--

```
    DECLARE @10001 INT = 20
    DECLARE @10002 INT = 40
    DECLARE @10003 INT = 60
    DECLARE @10004 INT = 80
    DECLARE @10005 INT = 100
```

--Update--

```
    UPDATE COA_DATE
    SET Amount = 
        CASE 
    --Sales Volume
            When GL_Account_No = 11000 Then @10001 * @10005
            When GL_Account_No = 11001 Then @10001 * @10004
            When GL_Account_No = 11002 Then @10001 * @10002
            When GL_Account_No = 11003 Then @10001 * @10003
            When GL_Account_No = 11004 Then @10001 * @10005
        END
```

---create a total of column 'GL_Account_No' ie.

```
sum(11000+11001+11002+11003+11004) = row name 'Sales Total'
```

---desired output

```
--GL_Account_No   Amount
--11000           120,000
--11001            96,000
--11002            48,000
--11003            72,000
--11004           120,000
--Sales Total     456,000
```

Comment: I don't understand, the total row should be insereted to the table? Or you want to select it? Or you already have a total row there?

Comment: It needs to be inserted, then once inserted needs to sum the total of the Amounts. Hope that's clear..thnx

Comment: Is gl_account_no column a string or a number? You can insert 'Sales Total' if its a number, you know that right?

Comment: I have set the data type as a number, each GL_Account_No is representative of a GL Account name (its for financial accounting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregations are usually better handled in some sort of reporting layer, rather than embedded in your SQL query: the language is designed to work with sets, and mixing data in your result set (some detail-level rows, a grand total row) generally leads to more trouble than it's worth.

Like all things that are not "usually" a good idea, there are exceptions. SQL Server has the `ROLLUP` operator for this circumstance: searching for "SQL ROLLUP" will find you a few good articles to get you started (such as [this one](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/24/sql-server-introduction-to-rollup-clause/) or [this one](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)).

After running the `UPDATE` statement in your original post, you can then retrieve the data from your table with code like the following (untested).

```
SELECT 
    gl_account_no
    ,SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM COA_DATE
WHERE gl_account_no IN (11000,11001,11002,11003,11004)
GROUP BY gl_account_no
WITH ROLLUP
```